# Pythonで複数の文字列のいずれにも一致しない条件式の書き方

Tags: python, python3

Python3で、複数の文字列（アプリケーションで保持する状態）のいずれにも一致しない条件式を下記のif文以外の方法で、短く書く方法はありますか？

```
status = 'status_invalid'
if (status != 'status_1') and (status != 'status_2') and (status != 'status_3'):
    print('invalid status')
```

Comment: [re.fullmatch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) を使う方法も考えられます。`import re` としておいて、`if not re.fullmatch(r'status_[1-3]', status): print('invalid status')`

Answer (score 3):

文字列の比較が単純な全文一致で良いなら、`not in`が使えると思います。

```
status = 'status_invalid'
if status not in ['status_1', 'status_2', 'status_3']:
  print('invalid status')
```